# Spacemacs: Refresh neotree when open another project buffer

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Is it possible to refresh projectile neotree in another project?

For example, I work on a buffer a of project A. And when I display buffer b in project B, I need to close and open neotree by SPC p t to see project B's projectile neotree.

I want to do this in one command.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer from Gitter.

treemacs was what I wanted.